# Data Truncation error using SQL Server 2016

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server

Data Truncation occur when trying to insert databases:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if ((proname.trim().equals("")) || prodesc.trim().equals(""))
        //if (proname.length() == 0|| prodesc.trim().equals(""))
        //(proname == null)
            z = "Silahkan Scan Barcode";
        else {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                } else {
                    String query = "insert into Producttbl (ProName,ProDesc,OnDate,Qty,Users,Locations) values ('" + proname + "','" + prodesc
                            + "','" + getDateTime()
                            + "','" + qty + "','"
                            + userid + "','"
                            + location2 + "')";

                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    z = "Added Successfully";
                    isSuccess = true;
                }
            } catch (final SQLException e) {

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(AddProducts.this, e.getMessage().toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
        return z;
    }
```

It's successful added when insert database manually directly type in edit text, but error when call from Master Data...

[Manual add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Y9S.png)

[Data from master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBHhh.png)

I need your help.

Comment: can you show us the query please, i can't see the image

Comment: You are leaving yourself open to a SQL injection with this code, use parameterised queries. Have a read here: https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/  That said, have you debugged through, and seen what is being passed, and then cross referenced this with the DB?

Comment: I use store procedure :

@ProName varchar(100) as (select * from ProductMaster where ProName=SUBSTRING(@ProName,1,19))

And then call it :

PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("EXEC viewProduct '"+edtproname.getText().toString()+"'");

Comment: You're currently using this: `String query = "insert into Producttbl (ProName,ProDesc,OnDate,Qty,Users,Locations) values ('" + proname + "','" + prodesc
                            + "','" + getDateTime()
                            + "','" + qty + "','"
                            + userid + "','"
                            + location2 + "')";

                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();`

Comment: @ModularSynth, so using the store procedure is recommended right? Still confuse with Data Truncation...

Comment: You can use views, stored procedures or triggers on the RDBMS side. Or use parametrized queries on the Android side. For the data truncation I can't say a thing, since I don't know your data structure, nor nothing. You only published a couple of images. Which aren't much useful.